# Java - String to StringReader

Tags: java

I have 3rd party library function which only takes Reader as parameter. And I have String that I need to pass into function. How do I do that ?

```
String s = "Some String";
StringReader sReader = new StringReader(s);

// 3rd Party Function Definition is public File saveResult(Reader source);
```

Can I do as  File aFile = saveResult(sReader); ? Or Should I create buffer and call read() first ?

I tried both way, and I am keep getting null pointer exception.

Comment: Can you please provide details on the exception you receive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this should be enough to serve your purpose:

```
String string = "Some String";
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(string);
File fileName = saveResult(stringReader); // calling Third party library method
```